# When to use different methods to solve Combinatorics problems.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The majority of combinatorics problems I've seen are solved using multiplication, the use of factorials, and combinations/permutations.

When I'm faced with a problem, I have no idea whether to use combinations, permutations, factorials or just multiplication. And when I look at the answer I always say "oh yeah, ofcourse!".

I know they all boil down to plain muliplication but when do I know which method I use for different combinatorics questions?

Sorry if this question seems too vague, I can add some examples of questions if you'd like.

Comment: May be we can help you much better if you give us an example and tell us what perplexes you exactly.

Comment: You should definitely add two or three examples.